# MySQL in docker won't persist changes to volume configured

Tags: mysql, docker, persistence

I am trying to run the offical docker image of Mysql 5.7.28 on MacOS, but I cannot manage to make it persistent.

I used mount point on docker host as well volume created with docker volume, but it doesn't work.

I use the following to create the container:

```
docker run \
--detach \
--name=dockMysql \
--env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" \
--publish 127.0.0.1:3307:3306 \
--volume=/Users/myuser/docker/dockMysql/data:/var/lib/mysql \
mysql:5.7.28
```

The data path: /Users/myuser/docker/dockMysql/data has all per

```
$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx   6 root  admin       192 May 24  2019 Users

$ pwd
/Users/myuser/docker/dockMysql/data

$ ls
auto.cnf        ca.pem          client-key.pem      ib_logfile0     ibdata1         mysql           private_key.pem     server-cert.pem     sys
ca-key.pem      client-cert.pem     ib_buffer_pool      ib_logfile1     ibtmp1          performance_schema  public_key.pem      server-key.pem
```

It seems mysql writes data in the host directory provided but doesn't save the data upon restart of the container.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks,
Ionut

Comment: Are you sure you are starting the new container with exactly the same bind mount ?

Comment: I run docker run command to create the container initially. Then I modify something and run docker stop/start.  After I stop it and restart it the changes are lost.  Files are on the disk as shown above. If I enable general log between startups it will write in the same file, but the variable setting is not saved.